# New tag for questions asking to identify objects to be reproduced?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

I'm going through our list of tags again - specifically those with the words '*identification*' and '*selection*' in them - and stumbled upon this post, for which no proper tag is available ([sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing)  is obviously wrong):

[What is the name of that type of cap?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/what-is-the-name-of-that-type-of-cap)

I'm not even entirely sure this question is on-topic, since it allows for any question of object identification as long as one adds that it's for an art or crafts project, but that is the crux of the matter:
**Is an [object-identification] tag useful**, or could it possibly be misused as a legitimization to ask to identify any object?
And would that be enough reason *not* to create such a tag?
Are there alternative tags we can use or create (I was thinking of [blueprint], which is likely too vague, or [prototyping], which might be too inconspicuous)?

Comment: There's an existing tag [style-identification].  It might fit under that (an apparel style).

Comment: @fixer1234 I created the [style-identification] tag only a while ago (and keep adding it to existing questions). I think it fits very distinct questions, and that it would be counter-intuitive to use in the cases mentioned above.

Comment: I have voted to close the question: identifying random objects, even if for an arts or crafts project, has essentially nothing do with either.

Comment: Just a little clarity to the question at hand. Are you more interested in a tag for new objects that are in need of receiving a catchy name. For example: How to coin a name with **”x”** object created by my friend two days ago? All said and done, I believe a new tag on this subject would be on topic on the main site.

Comment: @KenGraham Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking. The problem with the question linked here is that it asks for the identification of a certain existing mundane object, and whether or not we need a tag for that.